# View contents of Neo4j Spatial database

Tags: neo4j, spatial

With [these steps](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial#running-neo4j-spatial-code-from-the-command-line) from the Neo4j Spatial README on github.com I was able to import the [two-street.osm](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial/blob/master/two-street.osm) file.

The output looked like

```
=== Loading layer two-street.osm from two-street.osm ===
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Importing with osm-writer: OSMGraphWriter: DatabaseService[community single [/data]]:txInterval[5000]
two-street.osm[171]: Completed load in 1.493s
two-street.osm[171]:    Imported nodes:  0.635s
two-street.osm[171]:    Optimized index: 0.0s
two-street.osm[171]:    Imported ways:   -1.475139339345E9s
two-street.osm[171]:    Optimized index: 0.0s
two-street.osm[171]:    Imported rels:   1.475139340203E9s
Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 1970: Found 24 nodes during 0s way creation: 
        node-index:     23/0s   (108.49056603773585 nodes/second)
        changeset:  1/0s    (1000.0 nodes/second)
Loaded 24 nodes
Loaded 2 ways
two-street.osm[171]: info | Elapsed time in seconds: 1.495
Geometry statistics for 1 geometry types:
        LineString: 2
Tag statistics for 2 types:
        all: TagStats[all]: [highway, name]
        way: TagStats[way]: [highway, name]
two-street.osm[171]: Re-indexing with GraphDatabaseService: community single [/data] (class: class org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade)
Index[6]: info | Re-indexing elapsed time in seconds: 0.097
Geometry statistics for 1 geometry types:
        LineString: 2
=== Completed loading two-street.osm in 6.716 seconds ===
```

which seemed fine to me.

Now I want to see what it is *in* the database.

In the Neo4j Browser I tried to use

```
match (n) return n;
```

to list all contents of the database, but there aren't any nodes listed. Did I do something worng or do I have wrong understanding?

Comment: Just to confirm : did you load the data into an embedded instance of neo4j (as the docs show) and then open a browser up against a server instance of neo4j (i.e your browser instance was looking at a different db)

Comment: Oh my bad, this could be the case. I wasn't aware that the docs only show how to load into an embedded db - I thought it loads the data into the database running on the system where I executed the commands. How can I load the data into a real db then? @ChrisWhite